# What does "$" mean before a number in Delphi?

Tags: vb.net, delphi, syntax

I'm trying to convert Delphi code to vb.net and I'm not sure about this line:

```
stream.Seek($42, soFromBeginning);
```

I'm familiar with using seek on filestreams (in vb.net) but I'm not sure about the `$42`.

I'm assuming that corresponds to a position, but how does that translate to vb.net?

Answer (score 15):

$ is the prefix for a hexadecimal constant. In VB.NET, that's &H, so you would write &H42.

Comment: Delphi integer litterals allow 'x', '0x', and '$' to denote an hexadecimal notation.So '$' is not THE prefix.

Comment: @az01 I can believe 0x (although I was unaware of it and have yet to try it), but I'm absolutely certain that neither ax nor xa is an integer literal.

Comment: @az01 And now that I've tried it, I see that 0x is nonsense as far as Delphi is concerned too.

Comment: @Az01 was probably thinking about *strings* being converted to integers. The `Val` function accepts `$`, `x`, `X`, `0x`, and `0X` as hexadecimal prefixes, and `Val` is what's used by `StrToInt` and `Read`. But `Val` is not what's used when parsing the Delphi language; the compiler accepts only `$` for hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: @RobKennedy Thanks for that, I'm glad to see there's actually some truth in @az01's claim, even though it's unrelated to this question. Perhaps interestingly, I am unable to find the precise syntax accepted by `Val`, `StrToInt` or `Read` documented in the help, even in Delphi 7's help.

Comment: yes you're right, my innitial comment is totally OT, but it's too late to delete the comments now...

Answer (score 5):

The code required for VB.net is almost identical:

```
stream.Seek(&H42, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

The points of note here are:

- `$` in Delphi is the prefix for hexadecimal.
- The `soFromBeginning` corresponds to `SeekOrigin.Begin`.

Answer (score 1):

The $42 value is the offset from the beginning of the stream.

In VB.NET that would be :

```
reader.BaseStream.Seek(66, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
```