# how hexdecimal numbers incresment delphi

Tags: delphi

how can for example when I do in loop  but in hex decimal

```
for i =0 to 255 do
```

i need it

```
for i = 0 to ff \\255  dosomthing i:= i+1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545148/what-does-mean-before-a-number-in-delphi

Comment: `for i:= 0 to $ff {255} do  something`

Comment: You seem confused. A number is a number. Decimal, binary, hexadecimal etc. are just representations. Decimal 255 is the same number as hex ff. To specify hex representation in a literal, use the prefix `$`, e.g. `$ff`.

Comment: i wont to make comport command in a loop   for 255 after that make anaother loop that's mean  I wont to send  comport command  for 255 times

Comment: i wont to make comport command in a loop   for 255 after that make anaother loop that's mean  I wont to send  comport command  for 255 times  example                                                                                                        comport.writes('7e 00 01');
comport.writes('7e 00 02');
comport.writes('7e 00 03');
...........................
...........................
comport.writes('7e 00 09');
comport.writes('7e 00 0a');
comport.writes('7e 00 0b');
comport.writes('7e 00 0c');
...........................
...........................
comport.writes('7e 00 FF');

Comment: I found it with the increment  I used inttohex

Comment: You need to learn how to break the problem into pieces. Your problem here was knowing how to convert an integer into a hex string representation. Nothing like what was said in the question.